# What is the second argument of TensorFlow's tf.data.filter() that I find no documentation of?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I recently had a `TypeError` when using

```
def lie_filter(line):
    return tf.equal(line['lie_id'], 2)
```

in

```
dataset = (
    tf.data
    .TextLineDataset('shots.csv')
    .skip(1)
    .map(decode_line)
    .filter(lie_filter)
    .cache())
```

The exact error was `TypeError: lie_filter() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Simply changing the function signature to `lie_filter(line, x)` made the error go away and the filtering appears to work as intended. However, it left me wondering what is this mysterious second argument.

[TensorFlow manual for tf.data.filter()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter) only specifies one argument. There are also numerous examples by TensorFlow where filtering is done as per my attempt above. Take a look at, e.g., [imports85.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6d14dcba7225d205f2e7834551f42385802aa2cf/tensorflow/examples/get_started/regression/imports85.py#L116).

Printing the `x` inside `lie_filter` yields `Tensor("arg12:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`.

What is the second argument and where can I find documentation about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, of course I finally got it just after submitting the question. As I suspected, this was my own doing. The `map()` is returning a tuple of `(features, label)`. The second argument is of course the `label` as a tensor.

Hopefully this is of help for someone from the future :)